# How does the browser deal with jQuery .remove() and ChildNode.remove()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The scenario:

- Application built with jQuery 2.0.1.
- Your team prefers vanilla JavaScript.
- Options are [jQuery .remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).
- You need to remove a node `<div id="js-cancel"></div>`.

---

```
var jsCancel = document.getElementById('js-cancel');

jsCancel.remove();
```

---

Original Question: I'm assuming the browser will use jQuery to remove the element. Is that correct and why?

**Updated Question:** Internet Explorer does not support ChildNode.remove(). I'm assuming the browser will be guided by jQuery on what action should occur when it encounters .remove(). For the browsers that support ChildNode.remove(), do they reference jQuery first or skip it and go straight to the DOM API?

Comment: Until your client base is certain to take advantage of ES6 features like WeakMaps and until jQuery incorporates them *(maybe they do when available)*, jQuery can leak memory when *not* using jQuery to remove elements, assuming the elements (or descendants) have jQuery data attached.

Comment: ...if the team prefers vanilla JS, why not do the same and drop jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming the browser will use jQuery to remove the element

No, that's completely wrong.

The *browser* will never "use jQuery". jQuery is a library written for users, on-top of vanilla JavaScript and the DOM API.

jQuery will use the DOM APIs, not vice-versa.

---

RE: Your update

> Internet Explorer does not support `ChildNode.remove()`. I'm assuming the browser will be guided by jQuery on what action should occur when it encounters `.remove()`

Again, that's completely wrong.

If you go directly to the DOM API, jQuery is *absolutely uninvolved*. It performs no function at all, unless you actually *use it* as your interface to the DOM. It cannot "guide" the browser to do anything, unless you actually **use jQuery**. If you access the DOM API directly, you are consciously choosing to side-step jQuery.

All that will happen in IE is that you will get an exception, and your page will probably die.

> For the browsers that support ChildNode.remove(), do they reference jQuery first or skip it and go straight to the DOM API?

No, that makes no sense. When you invoke `ChildNode.remove()`, you **already are** going straight to the DOM API. The browser cannot choose whether to use "jQuery or skip it and go straight to the DOM API", if you've already gone there. It's done.

Comment: Are you saying jsCancel.remove() goes to straight to the DOM API and $(jsCancel).remove() is needed to reference the jQuery remove function? If this is so, than my setup of jsCancel.remove() will not work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yep, jsCancel.remove() does not work in IE. [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kemadomepi/1/edit?html,js,console,output) Glad this was caught before I used it everywhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Aaron  Yes, if you invoke a function that does not exist in IE, of course it will fail, regardless of whether jQuery is loaded in the page. jQuery isn't magic. It cannot change how method invocations work, or tell the browser to to do so, or provide the browser with alternatives to non-existent methods. I think this all stems from a fundamental misunderstanding on your part of how JavaScript works. Just because both methods are called `remove` doesn't make them related in *any way*.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider [`Node.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```js
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

It is much older (and thus much more supported) than `ChildNode.remove`.

In fact, jQuery's `remove` uses it:

```js
remove: function( selector, keepData /* Internal Use Only */ ) {
  var elem,
      elems = selector ? jQuery.filter( selector, this ) : this,
      i = 0;
  for ( ; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
    if ( !keepData && elem.nodeType === 1 )
      jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem ) );
    if ( elem.parentNode ) {
      if ( keepData && jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem ) )
        setGlobalEval( getAll( elem, "script" ) );
      elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem ); // <---
    }
  }
  return this;
}
```